# sql server datepart return

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a sql query that is grouping rows by calendar week

```
select count(*),datepart(wk,mydate)
from MyTable
where mydate between '12/26/2010' and '1/8/2011'
group by datepart(wk,mydate)
```

The date range is two weeks but three rows come back because Jan 1 is a saturday and is the only day in the range that `DATEPART` returns a `1` the other dates return `53` or `2`.

I want jan 1 to be grouped with the dates that return a 53, but I want it to be a generic answer not something like `CASE WHEN datepart(wk,mydate) = 53 then 1 else datepart(wk,mydate) end` because that will work for that specific date range not for other years.

I'm just wondering what a good solution would be

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want a generic solution, then please tell us how you decide generally whether week 1 should be merged with the last week of the last year. Is it only when week 1 contains only 1 day? Or when it is less than 4? Or always?

Comment: @antriy: in this query I consider Sun-Sat a week and want to group by that assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DateDiff() instead with your start date as the date to compare.

Answer (score 2):

We use to choose as week of a date, the week of his last sunday (first day of the week in SQL). So, for each date, you can ask for the week of his last sunday with the following query:

```
select count(*),datepart(wk,mydate-DATEPART(dw,mydate)+1)
from MyTable
where mydate between '12/26/2010' and '1/8/2011'
group by datepart(wk,mydate-DATEPART(dw,mydate)+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use [iso_week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) instead of `wk`.

```
select count(*),datepart(iso_week,mydate)
from MyTable
where mydate between '12/26/2010' and '1/8/2011'
group by datepart(iso_week,mydate)
```

Sample:

```
declare @T table (Val datetime)
insert into @T values
('2010-12-30'),
('2010-12-31'),
('2011-01-01'),
('2011-01-02'),
('2011-01-03'),
('2011-01-04'),
('2011-01-05')

select
  Val,
  datepart(iso_week, Val) as ISO_WEEK
from @T
```

Result:

```
Val                     ISO_WEEK
----------------------- -----------
2010-12-30 00:00:00.000 52
2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 52
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 52
2011-01-02 00:00:00.000 52
2011-01-03 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-04 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000 1
```

Comment: that still returns a 1 for Jan. 1 and 2 for jan 2. It seems like datediff is the solution i'm looking for

Comment: Not for me. It's week 52 for 1 and 2 jan. You might have an issue with first day of week is Monday.